# Weird SQLite query results on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table with three records in it.  I have a query that attempts to select any record that is expired by 60 minutes or more.

Two of the records are intentionally expired.

The following SELECT statement returns all three records to a cursor when ran with SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery in Android

```
SELECT * FROM T_ChalkedTire WHERE timestamp <= datetime('2017-08-16 11:33:28', '-60 minutes')
```

However, if I run this very same SELECT statement directly on the database using DB Browser for SQLite, it returns only the two properly expired records.

Why is this same query giving me different results when ran under Android?  It's like the Android query is ignoring the WHERE clause and just selecting all records.

Comment: How are you storing the timestamp value ? I recommend unixepoch.  See https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/datetime.php

Comment: I store the value as DATETIME yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss..

Comment: The query looks OK. Show the data in Android.

Comment: not sure why, but when I use in android db.rawQuery(selectRequest, whereClause); i get the wrong results returned to the cursor.. but if I put the entire statement into one string and run db.rawQuery(wholeStatement, null) then it works properly.. i'm fine with this, just weird